# SQLPackage : Import or Export SQL Azure BACPAC without users

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I know how to use `SQLpackage.exe`. I can export from SQL Azure and create a bacpac. I can also Import to SQL Server via `SQLPackage.exe`.

I want to export or import without the users in the database. The users are preventing the normal import to fail.

> Error importing database :could not import package.
>
> Error SQL72014 Cannot grant, deny or remove permissions to or from special roles
> [image]

I can't delete the users before I export, or exclude them from the import.

Currently we have to backup the database, restore it on SQLAzure, delete the use on this second database, then create a bacpac from the restored database.

How do I get around this?
can I use [IgnoreUserSettingsObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) with my sqlpackage ? I tried using the parameters but it fails

Comment: Did you try /P:IgnorePermissions switch?  I know in visual studio SSDT you can create a solution and you can delete individual objects from  you solution (not in the source) before you deploy. Of course you can only create .dacpac file and do the data separately.

Comment: Thanks, Just tried  /P:IgnorePermissions now, but did not work unfortunately.

Comment: I will do some test later on and keep you posted. I know for sure SSDT will solve you problem but I do not know how easy it is for you to switch to SSDT from sqlpackage.  What role (if you are allowed to share) you are having issue with?

Comment: Thanks @SqlWorldWide, it is a specific user on a different domain that exists in our SQL Azure database, that does not exist on any of the developers databases who want to restore it (not specific role).

Comment: so my 2 options are 1) SSDT and 2) dacpac with data afterwards?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify:  1. Using SSDT you can only export schema (not data).  First you create a solution, remove that use, do the build and deploy.  2. You have export data separately using other method.

Comment: OK thanks, I did use the data import method to import tables and their data, and it took a very very long time, therefore we decided I should find a different way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57293/discussion-between-sqlworldwide-and-peter-pitlock).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, but I coudn't find a way to generate the .bacpac without users, there is a workarround if you need the copy in the same suscription, the Microsoft Suport Team guide us is doing a [COPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell) directly from the Azure Portal and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).